# Cannot find module 'webpack' - BigCommerce

Tags: node.js, npm, bigcommerce

Needing to run a BigCommerce site locally and not sure why it's not running. It's running an older version of Cornerstone (V4.4.0) so not sure how to fix:

Node Version: V12.22.7

NPM: 6.14.15

Stencil version - 3.7.0

Error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'`
`Require stack:`

- `/path-to-directory/stencil.conf.js`
- `/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.7/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/BuildConfigManager.js`
- `/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.7/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/stencil-start/js`
- `/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.7/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/bin/stencil-start.js`

`at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)`
`at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)`
`at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)`
`at require (internal/modules/cjs/helps.js:74:18)`
`at Object. (path-to-directory/stencil.conf.js:1:15)`

As well as this:

`npm ERR! Error while executing:`
`npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/bigcommerce-labs/node-sass.git`
`npm ERR!`
`npm ERR! fatal: remote error:`
`npm ERR! The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.`
`npm ERR! Please see` [`https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/`](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/) `for more information.`
`npm ERR!`
`npm ERR! exited with error code: 128`

I have tried moving back Node version but error persists. Checked API key incase it needed to be updated and not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have any dependency in your package.json pointing to git://github.com url. Those are now deprecated, you must use https, e.g.
`git+https://github.com/bigcommerce-labs/node-sass.git`.

Comment: No dependencies in package.json.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you installed bigcommerce in the past, and I guess it was an older version. They had this issue with @bigcommerce/stencil-cli as in their node-sass fork used the deprecated url. It was fixed a few months ago. If that is a third party dependency it won't necessarily update automatically. Try to reinstall it from the scratch or forcefully upgrade bigcommerce to a newer version.

Comment: Done that so I'm on 3.12.0 now but issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same exact issue yesterday and I believe the answer has to do with recent update to security protocols outlined in the link that pops up in the errors in your console after running `npm i`.  What I think has happened is your remote git user setup is prepended with `git://`, which is no longer valid and must be prepended with `https://` instead.  If you run the following command in your terminal, it should adjust all of your repositories globally and you should no longer have an issue:

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

Now, try running `npm i` again and you should be good to go.
I found this solution while looking to solve this same issue at https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/959